# Why the string sent by POST method is wrongly parsed in Django backend while the same code works in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, pandas

The following code works well in Jupyter Notebook. It creates pandas DataFrame:

```
string = "NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TURNAROUND,DISTANCE_FROM_ORIGIN,DISTANCE_TO_TARGET\n1,VLG,M,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,45,2000,2000\n2,VLG,M,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,45,2000,2000\n3,VLG,M,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,45,2000,2000\n"

llist = np.array(string.splitlines())
new = []

for i in range(0,len(arr)):
   line = arr[i].split(",")
   new.append(line)

pd.DataFrame(new[1:],columns=new[0])
```

But when I integrate it in Django app, it incorrectly parses the inout string `csvData`.
The `csvData` is sent using POST method from React.js app to Django backend: `'&csvData='+JSON.stringify(this.state.csvData)` from the front-end.

This is how I read `csvData` in Django (very similar to the code that I tested in Jupiter Notebook)

```
csvData = str(request.GET.get('csvData'))

print("CSV", csvData)

arr = np.array(csvData.splitlines())

new = []
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    line = arr[i].split(",")
    new.append(line)

X = pd.DataFrame(new[1:],columns=new[0])

print("X",X.head())
```

The line `print("CSV", csvData)` prints the string that I used in Jupyter Notebook!!! It means that the inputs of the code are the same both in Django and in Jupyter Notebook.

However, I get the following result in Django:

```
X Empty DataFrame
Columns: ["NUM,...,2000, 2000\n14, VLG, ...]
[0 rows x 148 columns]
```

The version of Numpy is the same. I use the same machine for both tests.

Comment: what's the output if you print `csvData` before parsing

Comment: Note that you pass it through uri so make sure that your csvData is properly encoded and decoded on both sides..

Comment: @kudeh: Do you refer to Django or React.js? Where should I print?

Comment: @bigless: Yes, right. csvData is received in Django. It looks exactly the same as I posted in the question. So, how should I proceed?